# insert dataframe to hbase issue

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hbase

when i try to insert my dataframe into hbase using this [tutorial](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_sparksql_dataframes) .
after adding this script.

```
object HBaseRecord
{                                                                                                             
   def apply(i: Int, t: String): HBaseRecord = {
      val s = s"""row${"%03d".format(i)}"""       
      HBaseRecord(s,
      i % 2 == 0,
      i.toDouble,
      i.toFloat,  
      i,
      i.toLong,
      i.toShort,  
      s"String$i: $t",      
      i.toByte)
  }
}
```

i got this error:

```
error: too many arguments for method apply: (i: Int, t: String)HBaseRecord in object HBaseRecord
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but 'for' found.
```

how i can fix this error

Comment: This looks more or less like a typo you've introduced somewhere before this code block... Can you provide a minimum reproducible and verifiable example ? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: like i mentioned i'm using hbase example

Comment: yes and I saw the example and it looks good to me

Comment: did you have a solution for my error

Comment: `val data = (0 to 255).map { i =>  HBaseRecord(i, "extra")}` - do you have this code from tutorial or you replaced it with smth else? Where do you have `for` ?

Comment: i'm using spark shell; i got that error when i run this script : `object HBaseRecord
{                                                                                                             
   def apply(i: Int, t: String): HBaseRecord = {
      val s = s"""row${"%03d".format(i)}"""       
      HBaseRecord(s,
      i % 2 == 0,
      i.toDouble,
      i.toFloat,  
      i,
      i.toLong,
      i.toShort,  
      s"String$i: $t",      
      i.toByte)
  }
}`

Comment: did u able to resolve the issue?